# xcode provision error

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

i installed and setup all the certificates, provisions , etc. and selected the did what was needed in the project edit page. i have the device in the usb and once i build i get this error.

```
The iPhone “myname” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with which the application was signed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install provision on your iPhone (i.e. connect your iPhone to iTunes and drag provision file on iPhone icon in iTunes).

Comment: thanks i did that and in the bundle identifier i have 238238D.* and im getting this error: <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility>: error: CFBundleIdentifier '238238D.*' contains illegal character '*' what else would i put? i put that as my app id.

Comment: well it seems that your app id must contain only alphanumeric characters (no '*'). Try renaming 238238D.* to 238238D.FooBarApp